# latex table: include '\n' in a table cell?

Tags: char, latex

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l | l | c | c }
Name     & Hex      & dezimal     & C-char \\
<cr>     & 0x0D     & 13          & '\\r' \\     % should read '\r'
<lf>     & 0x0A     & 10          & '\\n' \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Escaping the `'\'` preceding `'n'` or `'r'` to e.g. `'\\n'` inserts a new line - as the `'\\'` at the end of the line does. 
Using `'\n'` or `'\r'` produces weird characters.
How can this be coded properly?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex

Answer (score 2):

To typeset a backslash in your document, use `\textbackslash`.

But since it's referring to C code, it might be nicer to format it appropriately in a monospaced font:

```
\verb|'\r'|
```

Instead of the pipe (`|`) you can choose any other character, as long as it doesn't appear in the enclosed text.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for the precise and very helpful answer. The question should have been raised in some other of the fast growing number of specialized forums. Thinkig about to start a cheat-sheet for this in the future ;c)